# How to get warp.js library to work correctly?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I don't really know if this library can be interesting to somebody else but it is challenging my self-esteem in several ways. The code is not from a real work but for learning purpose only. As you can see I was just trying to run a 'hello world' but there must be something unexplained in the official documentation (https://tinkeringwithstuff.com/posts/canvas-warping-with-javascript.html). For, if somebody is experienced with it, their help will be well accepted. Thanks.

```js
//input canvas   
    var c = document.getElementById("input_canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);


//viewport canvas
var warp = new Warp({
 input_canvas: $('#input_canvas').get(0),
 viewport_canvas: $('#viewport_canvas').get(0),
 top: 100,
 left: 100
});

warp.deform({
 center: {x: 100, y: 100},
 radius: 50,
 angle: 45
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://tinkeringwithstuff.com/projects/canvas_warp/warp.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

  
<img id="grid" width="220" height="277" src="https://rapidpurple.com/tool_src/i/151.png" alt="The Grid" style="display: none;">

<p>Canvases:</p>
<canvas id="vp_canvas" width="200" height="200" style="float: left"></canvas>
<canvas id="input_canvas" width="240" height="297" style="diaplay:none"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any elements with the **ID** of `scream` in your snippet...

Comment: you're right, i've fixed in my editor. "scream" should be "grid". Anyway, my console keep saying: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
    at Warp._init (warp.js:30)
    at new Warp (warp.js:12)
    at warp.php:24

Answer (score 1):

The `TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined` error you were receiving was a result of the Warp library being unable to ascertain the width of the canvas from the jQuery selector that was being passed in the options object. Switching out the jQuery selector for a vanilla JavaScript selector resolves the issue, as shown below.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("input_canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var img = new Image();
img.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJcAAACXAQMAAAAiUVs6AAAABlBMVEUEAgT8/vxJvsdeAAAAO0lEQVRIx+3QIQEAIBDAwG9ONKIQAYng+VGAAIhNTl7Eo1YcNovJoNOK9JGhlVZaaaWVVlpppZVWH1ldXoWGgHcSIkEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=';
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    
    var warp = new Warp({
        input_canvas: $('#input_canvas').get(0),
        viewport_canvas: document.getElementById("vp_canvas"),
        top: 100,
        left: 100
    });
    
    warp.deform({
        center: {x: 100, y: 100},
        radius: 50,
        angle: 45
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tinkeringwithstuff.com/projects/canvas_warp/warp.js"></script>
<p>Canvases:</p>
<canvas id="vp_canvas" width="200" height="200" style="float: left"></canvas>
<canvas id="input_canvas" width="240" height="297" style="display:none"></canvas>
```

N.B. For the purposes of this demo, I've also Base 64 encoded your image to avoid [tainting the canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) when loading the image from the rapidpurple.com server.